# Hololens 2 offline synchronization

Tags: hololens, photon

Did anyone try to synchronize the object's position between 2 Hololens 2 devices without an internet connection?

I am using Photon to do it for Hololens 2 glasses in the same LAN. When one player moves an object, other people can see it, but the real position of the object in the room is not matched, because each device has an independent coordination system.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to bind the holographic to the physical world. It is recommended to use [local spatial anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=anchorstore) to ensure anchored holograms stay precisely in place so that the holographic in different devices will remain fixed in the same position of the physical world, and then follow the doc [Local anchor transfers in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/out-of-scope/local-anchor-transfers-in-unity) to enable one HoloLens device to export an anchor to be imported by a second HoloLens device.

Comment: Thank @Hernando. I used spatial anchors to synchronize the position of the object. It worked well. Now is the next step, how will you synchronize the movement of the object? Local anchor transfers in each frame takes too much time.

Comment: Put your hologram under the anchor as a child object, and then synchronize the relative position of the hologram from the parent anchor.